# filtering table data still stays at the same page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, antd

New react developer here, here i have antd table with filtering system.
My question is like this: if there is much data in the table so that there are for example page 1 page 2 page 3(with these i mean [image])

for example if you click page 3 (in table) and above are filtering buttons and you click one of those buttons and scroll down, you can see it is still at page 3, how to make it so when button is clicked it should always go automatically to page 1. my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-surf-t9eh3?file=/src/Test.js

english is not my mother language so there could be mistakes

Answer (score 1):

From Table docs https://ant.design/components/table/ you can pass pagination props to your table. This means that you can pass on onChange and current to pagination element in order to reset pagination page when filtering.

Here is an example of how to manage pages using state:

```js
const [paginationPage, setPaginationPage] = useState(1);

return (
  <Table
    pagination={{
    current: paginationPage,
      onChange: (pageNum) => setPaginationPage(pageNum)
    }}
    dataSource={filteredEventsData}
    columns={tableColumns}
  />
)
```

You can now reset the current page anywhere with:

```
setPaginationPage(youPageNumber);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-banach-d7ff2?file=/src/Test.js

Comment: this is working, good, i have one question related to your code, as you can see there is filtering, when user clicks 'In Delivery' button then it should show all result which has state of 'InDelivery', in your code it shows 2 of them which is right, but when i'm clicking 'Order' button, then it should show those with state of 'Order' but as you can see it shows 'InDelivery' and 'Order', while it should only show 'Order' ... easy way to solve that ? briefly when clicking buttons it should filter according to that filter button, if order button is clicked then only orders should be shown

Comment: Thats just because in the sample data two rows had the same key which causes react with arrays to display some rows multiple times. Just change key for one of them and it will display correctly

Comment: If i change the key then its not working when i click ’in delivery’ button, how to make it possibly to have many with same key ? Because table state could have many ’in deliveries’, thats why i have filter to show all ’in deliveries’

Comment: Or do you have a way to make this possible, if for example ’in delivery’ filter is clicked then there can be many rows which state is ’in delivery’

Comment: You have to use another property on your data. The ID has to be unique but you could have a prop called type that is not unique and only used for filtering.

Comment: Could you possibly give working example here?

Comment: Updated https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-banach-d7ff2?file=/src/Test.js where each element in eventsData have another prop type that is used in setFilteredEventsData(eventsData.filter((f) => f.type === filter));
For questions not regarding the original post create a new post. :)

Comment: You just changed key name of it, that is not what i asked :D

Comment: This is not a discussion forum and these questions are not related to post. Make a new post for further questions you may have. But all i did was ensure key is unique and that your filtering uses another prop than key.

Comment: This was helpful. The "current" and setPagination thing was the stuff I was missing.